# Firebase Messaging failed to send notification to server app

Tags: android, firebase, firebase-cloud-messaging

I currently doing a food delivery app. When I added the food from food list and going to checkout at cart.java, the order is placed and request is submitted to firebase database but it wont send notification to server app. But the server app able to send notification to notify the client app. I tried to figure out what wrong with these codes but still cannot found out the error/bug.

Cart.java

```
public class Cart extends AppCompatActivity {

RecyclerView recyclerView;
RecyclerView.LayoutManager layoutManager;

FirebaseDatabase database;
DatabaseReference requests;

TextView txtTotalPrice;
FButton btnPlace;

List<Order> cart = new ArrayList<>();
CartAdapter adapter;

APIService mService;

@Override
protected void attachBaseContext(Context newBase) {
    super.attachBaseContext(CalligraphyContextWrapper.wrap(newBase));
}

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

    //add calligraphy
    CalligraphyConfig.initDefault(new CalligraphyConfig.Builder()
    .setDefaultFontPath("fonts/restaurant_font.otf")
    .setFontAttrId(R.attr.fontPath)
    .build());

    setContentView(R.layout.activity_cart);

    //Init service
    mService = Common.getFCMService();

    //Firebase
    database = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance();
    requests = database.getReference("Requests");

    //Init
    recyclerView = (RecyclerView)findViewById(R.id.listCart);
    recyclerView.setHasFixedSize(true);
    layoutManager = new LinearLayoutManager(this);
    recyclerView.setLayoutManager(layoutManager);

    txtTotalPrice = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.total);
    btnPlace = (FButton)findViewById(R.id.btnPlaceOrder);

    btnPlace.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {

            if (cart.size() > 0)
                showAlertDialog();
            else
                Toast.makeText(Cart.this, "Your cart is empty.", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

        }
    });

    loadListFood();
}

private void showAlertDialog(){

    AlertDialog.Builder alertDialog = new AlertDialog.Builder(Cart.this, R.style.Theme_AppCompat_Dialog_Alert);
    alertDialog.setTitle("One more step!");
    alertDialog.setMessage("Enter your address: ");

       LayoutInflater inflater = this.getLayoutInflater();
       View order_address_comment = inflater.inflate(R.layout.order_address_comment, null);

       final MaterialEditText edtAddress = (MaterialEditText)order_address_comment.findViewById(R.id.edtAddress);
       final MaterialEditText edtComment = (MaterialEditText)order_address_comment.findViewById(R.id.edtComment);

       alertDialog.setView(order_address_comment);
       alertDialog.setIcon(R.drawable.ic_shopping_cart_black_24dp);
       alertDialog.setPositiveButton("YES", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
           @Override
           public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {

               //create new request
               Request request = new Request(
                       Common.currentUser.getPhone(),
                       Common.currentUser.getName(),
                       edtAddress.getText().toString(),
                       txtTotalPrice.getText().toString(),
                       "0",
                       edtComment.getText().toString(),
                       cart
               );

               //submit to firebase
               String order_number = String.valueOf(System.currentTimeMillis());
               requests.child(order_number).setValue(request);

               //delete cart
               new Database(getBaseContext()).cleanCart();

               sendNotification(order_number);

           }
       });

       alertDialog.setNegativeButton("NO", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
           @Override
           public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {
               dialog.dismiss();
           }
       });

    alertDialog.show();


}

private void sendNotification(final String order_number) {

    DatabaseReference tokens = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference("Tokens");

    //get all node with isServerToken is true
    Query data = tokens.orderByChild("serverToken").equalTo(true);
    data.addValueEventListener(new ValueEventListener() {
        @Override
        public void onDataChange(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {
            for(DataSnapshot postSnapShot:dataSnapshot.getChildren()){

                Token serverToken = postSnapShot.getValue(Token.class);

                //create raw payload to send
                Notification notification = new Notification("iDelivery", "You have new order " + order_number);
                Sender content = new Sender(serverToken.getToken(), notification);

                mService.sendNotification(content).enqueue(new Callback<MyResponse>() {
                    @Override

                    public void onResponse(Call<MyResponse> call, Response<MyResponse> response) {
                        //only run when get result
                        if (response.code() == 200) {
                            if (response.body().success == 1) {
                                Toast.makeText(Cart.this, "Thank you, Order placed.", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                                finish();
                            } else {
                                Toast.makeText(Cart.this, "Failed to place order.", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

                            }
                        }
                    }

                    @Override
                    public void onFailure(Call<MyResponse> call, Throwable t) {
                        Log.e("ERROR", t.getMessage());
                    }
                });

            }
        }

        @Override
        public void onCancelled(DatabaseError databaseError) {

        }
    });
}

private void loadListFood() {

    cart = new Database(this).getCarts();
    adapter = new CartAdapter(cart,this);
    adapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
    recyclerView.setAdapter(adapter);

    //calculation total price
    float total = 0;
    for(Order order:cart)
        total +=(Float.parseFloat(order.getPrice()))*(Integer.parseInt(order.getQuantity()));
    Locale locale = new Locale("en","MY");
    java.text.NumberFormat fmt = java.text.NumberFormat.getCurrencyInstance(locale);
    txtTotalPrice.setText(fmt.format(total));
}

@Override
public boolean onContextItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
    if (item.getTitle().equals(Common.DELETE))
        deleteCart(item.getOrder());
    return true;
}

private void deleteCart(int position) {

    //remove item at List<Order> by position
    cart.remove(position);

    //after that,delete all old data from SQLite
    new Database(this).cleanCart();

    //final,update new data from List<Order> to SQLite
    for (Order item:cart)
        new Database(this).addToCart(item);

    //refresh
    loadListFood();
}
}
```

MyFirebaseMessasing.java

```
public class MyFirebaseMessaging extends FirebaseMessagingService {

@Override
public void onMessageReceived(RemoteMessage remoteMessage) {
    super.onMessageReceived(remoteMessage);
    sendNotification(remoteMessage);
}

private void sendNotification(RemoteMessage remoteMessage) {
    RemoteMessage.Notification notification = remoteMessage.getNotification();
    Intent intent = new Intent(this, MainActivity.class);
    intent.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP);
    PendingIntent pendingIntent = PendingIntent.getActivity(this, 0, intent, PendingIntent.FLAG_ONE_SHOT);

    Uri defaultSoundUri = RingtoneManager.getDefaultUri(RingtoneManager.TYPE_NOTIFICATION);
    NotificationCompat.Builder builder = new NotificationCompat.Builder(this,"")
            .setSmallIcon(R.mipmap.ic_launcher_round)
            .setContentTitle(notification.getTitle())
            .setContentText(notification.getBody())
            .setAutoCancel(true)
            .setSound(defaultSoundUri)
            .setContentIntent(pendingIntent);

    NotificationManager noti = (NotificationManager)getSystemService(Context.NOTIFICATION_SERVICE);
    noti.notify(0, builder.build());
}
}
```

Answer (score 0):

**Try to add:**

```
Log.d(TAG, " response = "+response);
```

**As the following:**

```
mService.sendNotification(content).enqueue(new Callback<MyResponse>() {

      @Override

                public void onResponse(Call<MyResponse> call, Response<MyResponse> response) {

                    Log.d(TAG, " response = "+response);

                    //only run when get result
                    if (response.code() == 200) {
                        if (response.body().success == 1) {
                            Toast.makeText(Cart.this, "Thank you, Order placed.", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                            finish();
                        } else {
                            Toast.makeText(Cart.this, "Failed to place order.", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

                        }
                    }
                }

                @Override
                public void onFailure(Call<MyResponse> call, Throwable t) {
                    Log.e("ERROR", t.getMessage());
                }
            });
```

**Response looks like:**

```
{protocol=h2, code=401, message=, url=https://fcm.googleapis.com/fcm/send}
```

If you receive a 401 HTTP status code, your server key is not valid.